# JAVA_HOME doesnt work with sudo mvn

Tags: java, shell, environment-variables

I'm trying to run simple maven commands like `mvn clean install`. They dont seem to work with `sudo` , i get an error about 
    `Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute`

Im pretty sure `JAVA_HOME` is setup correctly since it works when I( run without sudo. Anyone know what's going on?